# How to use two versions of nodeJS in different projects at the same time?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have two projects and each is configured to use a version of NodeJS.
The first is configured to use version 18.8.1 and the other to 14.17.0
I need to run both at the same time, but when I do nvm use, the node version switches to both.
I can't use version 18 on one and 14 on the other.
Whenever I do nvm use, both projects switch versions.

Answer (score 1):

nvm switches the node version only on the current shell session as default, so you could open two different instances of your terminal/shell and switch between node version then execute your desired node project